# Water around window and door

Tags: windows, moisture, water-damage, window-frame

I just moved to a new house. After first rain I have noticed wet patch by the window and door.

I removed the skirting boards to find even more dampness and wet dust.

I asked the developer to fix it. They have initially put sealant between the window sill and the window frame. I told them this is not an acceptable solution as no other windows have sealant yet they don't let the water through. I told them this looks like incorrectly installed window.

The house is a brick house with insulated cavity.

Has anyone came across similar issue?

Upstairs windows have internal window sill that is hiding the floor. Im worried there might be more issues but removing window sills is a lot of effort...

On that note does anyone have any suggestions how to check it without removing window sill?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a newly built house or a new house to you?

Comment: that might be new house for you, but the house is not new, probably 20 or more years old

Comment: is there a positive drainage plan on the exterior window sill ?  I can see water on the exterior of your window which is going to end up on your exterior sill which if flat or sloped to inside will cause the water to want to come inside.

Comment: This is a new build house. Why does it look 20 years old!?

Comment: Fresh may I ask should there be something between window frame and window sill preventing the water from coming in?